# Rails form submit to controller action and jQuery modal

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, modal-dialog

I want a form to submit (POST) that a custom action in my controller that will perform an evaluation (based on the data from the form) and then pop up a jQuery model that has the results of that evaluation. The trick is, I want this modal to just pop over the form so that if they close the modal, they can go back and see/edit the form.

I've tried something like the following, but it does not work. I get the following error:

*Missing template games/evaluate, application/evaluate with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml]}.*

**/app/controllers/games_controller.rb**

```
class ExercisesController < ApplicationController
  #...    
  def evaluate
    if( params[:id] )
      found = Game.find(params[:id])
      @eval = found.evaluate_guess(params[:guess])
    end  
  end
  #...
end
```

**/app/views/games/play.html.haml**

```
= semantic_form_for @games, :url => evaluate_path(@games) do |f|
  = f.semantic_errors
  = f.input :guess, 
    :as => :text
= f.actions do
  = f.action :submit, :label => "Guess!",
    :button_html => { :action => :evaluate, :method => :post }
```

**/app/views/games/_evaluation_modal.html.haml**

```
#evaluation_modal.modal.modal-wide.hide.fade
  = semantic_form_for @exercise, html: { class: 'modal-form' } do |f|
    .modal-header
    %h3 Results

    .modal-body
      #flashbar-placeholder
      %h2= CGI.unescapeHTML(@eval).html_safe
```

**/app/views/games/evaluate.js.coffee**

```
$('#evaluate').html(
  '<%= escape_javascript render partial: "evaluation_modal"  %>')
$('#evaluation_modal').modal('show')
```

**/config/routes.rb**

```
#...
get '/play/:id' => 'games#play', as: :play
patch '/play/:id' => 'games#evaluate', as: :evaluate
#...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `:remote => true` to your `play` form.

```
= semantic_form_for @games, :url => evaluate_path(@games), :remote => true do |f|
```